# Can someone walk me through this gas mixture question?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

> Argon $(\ce{Ar})$ and helium $(\ce{He})$ are initially in separate compartments of a container at $\pu{25 °C}.$ The $\ce{Ar}$ in compartment **A** which has a volume $V_\ce{A}$ of $\pu{9.00 L}$ and a pressure of $\pu{2.00 bar}.$ The $\ce{He}$ in compartment **B** of unknown volume $V_\ce{B}$ has a pressure of $\pu{6.00 bar}.$ When the two compartments are connected and the gases allowed to mix, the total pressure of gas is $\pu{3.60 bar}.$ Assume both gases behave ideally.
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{|l|l|}
> \hline
> \text{Chamber A} & \text{Chamber B} \\
> V_\ce{A} = \pu{9.00 L} & V_\ce{B} = \pu{??? L} \\
> p_\ce{A} = \pu{2.00 bar} & p_\ce{B} = \pu{6.00 bar} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> **[4 marks]** Determine the volume of compartment **B**.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while.  Could someone walk me through the beginning steps? I should be good to go with some guidance.  Would I use Boyle's law in attempt to find the final volume once the partition is removed?

Comment: Have you watched this Youtube mini 8 min lecture, it addresses exactly the same problem on board... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFwFxgWDm5U.

Comment: @M.Farooq  I watched the lecture, but didn't know how to approach without any values for n.  I can determine the number of moles in chamber A, but I'm not sure how I would do that for chamber B or the final mixture.

Comment: You can determine the moles of Ar from its pressure temperature and volume using PV=nRT.

Comment: @M.Farooq Using the equation Pfinal = RTfinal[(n1+n2)/(V1+V2)], I still have 2 unknowns, n2 and V2. Is there a way to find n2 with my current information?

Comment: You need one more equation to set-up. Two unknowns require two equations. What if you set up PV=nRT for helium? P is given, V is unknown, n is unknown and RT are known. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: When I used those equations in a system of equations, I got negative values.  Ignoring the negative sign, it still didn't provide the correct final pressure when input into the ideal gas law for the final values.

Comment: Getting a negative sign is a red flag that some arithmetic or algebra is wrong. I don't see any other approach besides solving two equations with two unknowns. Did you convert temperature to Kelvin and the units of R are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Solve for the amount of gas in A: $n_A=p_AV_A/RT=\pu{0.727 mol}$. You'll need to perform necessary unit conversions or use R in units that match the given T, p and V units.
2. Write the volume of chamber B in terms of knowns: $V_B=n_BRT/p_B=n_B \times\pu{4.13\times 10^3 m^3/mol}$.
3. Write the total volume when mixed: $V_{tot}=n_{tot}RT/p_{tot}=n_{tot} \times\pu{6.89\times 10^3 m^3/mol}$.
4. Solve this last expression for $n_B$ after inserting the equalities $V_{tot}=V_A+V_B$, $n_{tot}=n_A+n_B$  and the result of step 2: 
   $$\begin{align} V_A+V_B &=(n_A+n_B)\times \pu{6.89\times 10^{-3} m^3/mol}\\ &=V_A + n_B \times\pu{4.13\times 10^{-3} m^3/mol}\\\rightarrow n_B &= \frac{V_A - n_A\times \pu{6.89\times 10^{-3} m^3/mol}}{\pu{2.75\times 10^{-3} m^3/mol}} = \pu{1.45 mol}\end{align} $$
5. Compute the volume in chamber B: $V_B=\frac{n_{B}RT}{p_B}=\pu{6.00\times 10^{-3} m^3}$

It's usually a good idea to perform a check to see if we did things right. Compute back the final pressure: $p_{tot}=\frac{n_{tot}RT}{V_{tot}}=\pu{3.60 bar}$.

Answer: $V_B = \pu{6.00 L}$